# How can I read in my file line by line with each line as a list of floats?

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, file-io

I have a file where each line has a pair of coordinates like so:

```
[-74.0104294, 40.6996416]
```

The code that I'm using to read them in is:

```
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt', 'r') as f:
    mVerts = f.read().splitlines()
```

This reads in all 78 lines into a list, but it reads them in as strings, so when I print them out it shows up as:

```
['[(-74.0104294, 40.6996416]', ... , '[-74.0104294, 40.6996416]']
```

(Imagine the ... as 76 more coordinates like the first and last)

How can I read in each of these coordinate pairs as a list so that I am left with a list of 78 sublists with 2 floats inside each sublist?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `'[(-74.0104294, 40.6996416]'`? ie, the extra opening parentheses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line, you need to:

1. **Read it**
   ... using a `for` loop to iterate over the file
2. **Strip whitespace including newlines**
   ... using `str.strip()`
3. **Lose the first and last characters (brackets)**
   ... using [string slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1014938): `[1:-1]`
4. **Split on the substring `', '`**
   ... using `str.split()` and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
5. **Convert the resulting strings into floats**
   ... using `float()`
6. **Add each pair of floats to a list**
   ... using `list.append()`

That looks like this:

```
m_verts = []
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pair = [float(s) for s in line.strip()[1:-1].split(", ")]
        m_verts.append(pair)
```

After which, `m_verts` looks like this:

```
>>> m_verts
[[-74.0104294, 40.6996416], ... ]
```

In general, you're better off iterating over the lines of a file than reading them all into a list at once with methods like `splitlines()` ... it's more readable, and with large files much more efficient.

Also, notice that I've used the more pythonic *under_score* style to name `m_verts`, rather than your *camelCase* style - and that there's no need to specify `'r'` when opening a file for reading.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus In my answer I used `ast.literal_eval` you probably don't know

Answer (score 0):

even better way than @ZeroPiraeus solution use ast.literal_eval which can evaluate any literal of python (here a list literal compound of float literal)

```
import ast
m_verts = []
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pair = ast.literal_eval(line)
        m_verts.append(pair)
```

but for construction of the list even better is list comprehension

```
import ast
with open('Manhattan_Coords.txt') as f:
    m_verts = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```